Multi user type inheritance (table-per-hierarchy) using Identity table in EF Core / .NET Core
I am doing a project using .NET Core and SQL Server. I am using a database first approach. I am trying to achieve table-per-hierarchy inheritance.
This is my code:
public  class ApplicationUser: IdentityUser
{       
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}  

public class Employer : ApplicationUser
{     
    public string employerName { get; set; }
    public string employerWebsite { get; set; } 
}

HomeController code:
private readonly UserManager<Application> customerManager;

public HomeController(UserManager<Employer> _customerManager)
{           
    customerManager = _customerManager;
}
  
public async Task<ActionResult> IndexAsync()
{
    var emp = new Employer() 
                  { 
                      Email = "cutomer1@hotmail.com", 
                      UserName = "Tom" , 
                      employerName = "Harry"
                      employerWebsite = "ghfhgf@hhh.com"
                  };

    var result = await customerManager.CreateAsync(emp, "Password01!");          
}      

This code is working fine. I am able to create an employer in Identity (AspNetUser) table. It also populates the Discriminator column.
The following error occurs when I try to login as an Application user:
 SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.  
 Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetString(int i)
 
 Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetString(int i)  
 lambda_method602(Closure, QueryContext, DbDataReader, ResultContext, SingleQueryResultCoordinator)    
 Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable<T>+AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()

 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable<TResult>+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()

 Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync<TSource>(IAsyncEnumerable<TSource> asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)   
 Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync<TSource>(IAsyncEnumerable<TSource> asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  
 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager<TUser>.FindByNameAsync(string userName) 
 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager<TUser>.PasswordSignInAsync(string userName, string password, bool isPersistent, bool lockoutOnFailure)  
 ArevnaHireWebApp.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.LoginModel.OnPostAsync(string returnUrl) in Login.cshtml.cs  
 
 var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);   
 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.ExecutorFactory+GenericTaskHandlerMethod.Convert<T>(object taskAsObject)  
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.ExecutorFactory+GenericTaskHandlerMethod.Execute(object receiver, object[] arguments)  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeHandlerMethodAsync()

 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeNextPageFilterAsync()

 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Rethrow(PageHandlerExecutedContext context)  
 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)  
 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()

 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)  
 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)   
 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)  
 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)  
 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)  
 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)  
 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Login page:
public class LoginModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly ILogger<LoginModel> _logger;

    public LoginModel(SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager, ILogger<LoginModel> logger)
    {
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _logger = logger;
    }
}





   public class InputModel
   {
             
      [Display(Name = "Title")]
      [Required(ErrorMessage = "Title is required")]
      public int TitleID { get; set; }

      [Required]
      [DataType(DataType.Text)]
      [Display(Name = "First Name")]
      public string FirstName { get; set; }

      [Required]
      [DataType(DataType.Text)]
      [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
      public string LastName { get; set; }

      [Required]
      [EmailAddress]
      [Display(Name = "Email")]
      public string Email { get; set; }

      [Required]
      [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least 
      {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
      [DataType(DataType.Password)]
      [Display(Name = "Password")]
      public string Password { get; set; }

 
      [DataType(DataType.Password)]
      [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
      [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and 
      confirmation password do not match.")]
      public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
      }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl 
    = null)
{
    returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");

    ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
       // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
       // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
       var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password,                  Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
    }


What is "Input"?? Normally on a login the client sends the userId (email) and password in the POST as parameters (url or message body). There is no references for 2-way binding in MVC or Razor applications.

If you are using database first approach, then show the sql code for creating tables.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You can check if there are these fields in you table and if they are NULL,When my feilds are NULL,I make the same mistake you do,I replace the NULL to a value,It works well.Then I delete the account register again,But there's something goes wrong.I'm very sorry that I can't give you a solution. you can learn more from this:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/add-user-data?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-8.0
